# HeidiSQL - crash after session broken - how to fix

Tags: heidisql

After stopping a local docker container, I found that HeidiSQL connecting to it crashes with "overflow error" or something alike. Then, when I restart the application, it just keeps crashing at startup and nothing can be done to recover. So, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can enter the installation folder and find `portable_settings.txt`, and delete lines beginning with:

- "Last session"
- "Last active session"

And all setting lines of the corrupted connection. You may lose some connection details, but HeidiSQL will recover to be usable.